# How can I assign a separate name to a variable with a comma?

Tags: python, selenium, python-2.7, code-separation

Hello stackoverflow users. Today i want to ask for your help with something what is only a small part of my project. 
So... I have already done small application using Selenium to get text from div, text is not static, it changes with the character moves. Let me show:

```
botloc = driver.find_element_by_id('botloc').text
    print botloc
```

I already looped it, so i can get update every 0,5sec (character moves 1 square within half a second). Of course i know its better to bind with key, but loop works fine for me when its in testing phase.

[example] **Output** of one botloc looks like that:

```
26,20
```

This is x and y from actuall position, so I want to use that comma like a separator to separate x and y, then i can assign each of them to single name(def, class, whatever).

[example]**Output** of 5 x botloc when I move my character looks like that:

```
28,20
28,21
28,22
29,22
30,22
```

So basically, it's all about square map, but i dont know the idea how to use that, so i created my own idea with simple logic and mathematics.

I am also trying to understand information from here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html but for now I wants to do homework is described above.

I was trying to use:

```
firstpart, secondpart = botloc[:len(botloc)/2], botloc[len(botloc)/2:]
```

But after including it to my code my `botloc` is not working (no error, no text, just white), and the separator too, is any possibility to fix that?

Thanks for your understanding for me-new python learner!

Comment: what parts of that documentation would you like explained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> botloc="28,20"
>>> botX,botY = map(int,botloc.split(','))
>>> botX,botY
(28, 20)
```

If you wanted to store multiple bot locations you could do this:

```
>>> botLocations = []
>>> botLocations.append(map(int,botloc.split(',')))
>>> botLocations
[[28, 20]]
```

Where each time yout get a new `botloc` you split it by commas, convert each value seperated into an int, and store it inside botLocations.

---

```
botloc[:len(botloc)/2], botloc[len(botloc)/2:]
```

Wouldn't work if botLoc was uneven i.e `198,2`. Instead you would have to do something like

```
>>> botloc="28,20"
>>> botloc[:botloc.index(',')]
'28'
>>> botloc[botloc.index(',')+1:]
'20'
```

To seperate the string.

Comment: Already tested def with looped botloc,botX,botY. The result is perfect: `>>> repeat()
29,16
29
16` but i dont understand how to store locations, is store something like a dictionary? I must add each value manually? or can i automatize that process to build full store just by moving my character on every single square?